# How to maintain B-tree invariants when elements vary in size?

Tags: database, b-tree

For a B-tree of order m, every node except the root must contain m-1 to 2m-1 elements, where every element is at least a key and maybe also some additional data (e.g., a value).  Yet each node must have some constant total size picked to give good performance on the underlying block device.  So what happens if your elements are of variable size?

SQLite3 seems to have a scheme for tacking additional block-sized pieces onto its nodes, and MySQL lets you declare the size of your records (e.g., you can type your fields to be not just strings but strings under some size).  What other solutions are there?  And what do people think about when picking one over the other?

**edit**: And by the previous sentence, I mean, what do *database developers* think about when *deciding to implement their B-trees* one way over the other?

(I'm in a databases course right now, so I'm more interested in the theory and design angle than in details of particular systems.)

Answer (score 1):

I know that SQL Server can have key length up to 900 bytes at a page size of 8192 bytes. If you actually have 900 bytes keys only 9 (or 8) rows will fit on an index'es intermediate-level pages. This just means that the branching factor is lower than usual. This might violate the theoretical B-tree invariant but this is just an academic concern which does not impede performance in a significant way. It does not change asymptotic complexity of the algorithms involved.

In short: This is a purely academic concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite a good question. Although RDBMS vendors all have slightly different implementations, the underlying theory is the same and I doubt anyone uses b-tree implementations as the determining factor in choosing a vendor.

As I understand it, the basic structure of each b-tree page contains keys and pointers. The pointers continually reference other pages containing more keys and pointers with the final pointer referencing the associated data record.

How to Handle variable length keys is interesting. Perhaps others can shed some light on vendor specific solutions.

Comment: Ah, right, I mean, "what do database developers think about when implementing their B-trees one way or the other?"  Edited for clarity now, thanks!

Comment: B-tree's are associated with the creation of indexes. Developer's need to understand the concept of Clustered and Non-CLustered Indexes for T-SQL, hash and b*tree clusters and hash clusters for Oracle. Indexes are important to understand and I recommend you find a book that include chapters on this subject.